# variables inside a php sendmail form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, sendmail

im a beginner in php / mysql so go easy on me :)

I made a very basic php order form for our work which has lots of dropdown boxes.
This submits the results via an email using sendmail in php.

Now im trying to make it dynamic using a sql database.

I have the form set up using the sql and php, but my problem lies in the sending of the dynamically generated data.

I have all the variables available by using this line

```
extract($_POST['orderdetails'], EXTR_SKIP);
```

the variables end up as $vanilla00, $vanilla06, $vanilla11, etc...

So now I have this code to create the table using these variables

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultbline))

{$message   .="<tr><td>" 
. $row['prod_name'] 
. "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td>
<td>$" . $row['prod_selectname'] . "0</td>
<td>$" . $row['prod_selectname'] . "6</td>
<td>$" . $row['prod_selectname'] . "11</td>
<td>$" . $row['prod_selectname'] . "18</td>
<td>$" . $row['prod_selectname'] . "t</td>
<td>$" . $row['prod_selectname'] . "24</td>
<td>$" . $row['prod_selectname'] . "36</td>" ;
}
```

The prod_selectname is taken from the database and in this instance will be vanilla, so the final table ends up reading

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultbline))

{$message   .="<tr><td>" 
. $row['prod_name'] 
. "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td>
<td>$vanilla0</td>
<td>$vanilla6</td>
<td>$vanilla11</td>
<td>$vanilla18</td>
<td>$vanillat</td>
<td>$vanilla24</td>
<td>$vanilla36</td>" ;
}
```

the problem is that the resulting email shows the variable name (ie vanilla18) instead of treating it as a variable.

Am I missing some  . { ( [ or other code somewhere ?

Sorry to be so thorough, but I dont know how else to explain it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should be outputted?

Comment: That's because you are concatenating `$row['prod_selectname']` as string.

Comment: tastro: The output should be the value of "$vanilla18" etc, but it is outputting the variable name instead of the value.
If change the code
    <td>$" . $row['prod_selectname'] . "18</td>
to 
    <td>$vanilla18</td>
then it works, so the variable is there
But that isnt a viable option as there are 100s of variables, and I want it dynamic.

machineaddict: Im not sure what that means, or how to resolve it. ( I am a newbie to php )

thanks

Comment: If `$row['prod_selectname']` is always "vanilla" then just simply do: `' . $vanilla0 . '` instead of `'$' . $row['prod_selectname'] . '0'` or use the answer which machineaddict provided. It should work with $$.

Comment: no the prod_selectname is dynamic.
There are over 100 different values for this. 
Only 1 of them is vanilla

Comment: Check machineaddict's answer. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are concatenating `$row['prod_selectname']` as string.
Before you echo each variable you need to name it dinamically, like this:

```
$var_name = $row['prod_selectname'] . "0";
```

When you echo the variable, it will be like this:

```
"<td>" . echo $$var_name . "</td>";
```

Comment: but my 
$var_name
is dynamically made from the prod_selectname and a number after it ?

Comment: I cant work out where that code goes :(
If I place them one after another like above, then I get errors highlighted.
Do I need your first line before each of my lines that need the variable ?

Comment: You could put it where I said, but you would have to close the string first. That's why you are getting errors.

Comment: Thankyou.
This part of my task is now working.
I tried to + rep but it wont let me as I have less that 15 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultbline))
{

    $var1 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "0";
    $var2 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "6";
    $var3 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "11";
    $var4 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "18";
    $var5 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "t";
    $var6 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "24";
    $var7 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "36";

    $message .="<tr><td>"
            . $row['prod_name']
            . "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td>
            <td>" . $$var1 . "</td>
            <td>" . $$var2 . "</td>
            <td>" . $$var3 . "</td>
            <td>" . $$var4 . "</td>
            <td>" . $$var5 . "</td>
            <td>" . $$var6 . "</td>
            <td>" . $$var7 . "</td>
";
}
```

But machineaddict posted this first... So give him the credit. ;)

Comment: awesome.. between yoursef and machineaddict it seems to be working now :)
But the vars in your post, I had to move inside the "while loop" so that each row's values are created.
many thanks to both of you :)

Comment: @MerseyRay you are right... I was just typing the code fast and didn't pay attention to it. I have updated the code in my answer. ;) Select machineaddict's answer as your solution if it's what solved your question.